# Caps lock to control: not accepted by Blender

Tags: shortcut, linux

I have a question about the keyboard input handling of Blender.

I'm running Kubuntu 14.10, and set up my <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> such that it acts like an extra <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key (System Settings → Input Devices → Keyboard → Advanced → Caps Lock key behavior → Make Caps Lock an additional Ctrl)

Every application simply sees it as just another <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key. Blender, however, now ignores the key altogether. Pressing <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> acts as if I just pressed <kbd>W</kbd>. The Python scripting console also keeps typing in lower case after pressing <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>, which shows that it's no longer interpreted as <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> either.

This happens when running Blender 2.72b, as well as when I compile my own Blender from Git.

Who can help me solve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apparently, the KDE settings aren't as "low level" as Blender's input system. This command, however, is:

`setxkbmap -option ctrl:nocaps`

It also makes Caps Lock an additional Ctrl, but at such a low level that Blender understands it too.

Source: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MovingTheCtrlKey